# Release pipeline - manual status override

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I've got Azure DevOps release pipeline for our web apps with two stages:
staging (production slot) and production.

Both of those stages have a task to run integration tests against those environments as the final step.

Sometimes, due to the nature of the live environment (data), some of the tests may fail. That doesn't mean there's an issue with the app.

Once that happens, the release to that environment is marked as Failed (rejected), which is correct from process point of view, but then manual inspection can reveal that it was only a data issue, thus it's ok to keep it.

Is there any way to manually change the status (via GUI or API)? So it no longer appears as Failed on the dashboard.

I can't find anything in the GUI. I was able to find Manual Interventions in the API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/manual%20interventions?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1), but without any details on what it does.

Redeployment is not guaranteed to be successful from data perspective hence the need to manually override the status.

Edit:
This is what I'm currently getting when it fails, but I'd like to be able to turn the red stage into green.

[image: Release dashboard showing failed production stage]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using option "Trigger even when the selected stages partially succeed" that is available in the pre-deployment condition.

Then I saw option to manually deploy the prod environement.

[image: enabling option in pre-deployment condition]

[image: failed dev environement and success prod]

Comment: Thanks @Kamil for the answer. I have edited my question to include an image showing our current release status. When it fails on the final stage like in the picture, this suggested option will not affect the failed status. Which can raise alarm bells if someone looks at the dashboard and isn't familiar with the release activities.

Comment: can you also show me what tasks you have in the last stage?

Comment: I can't see the way to manually modify the statu of the pipeline.

Comment: The status is something that is automatically created, based on the code that you would write.
I have two suggestions:
1) make a separate pipeline that would be responsible only for tests. Then you will know quickly, that only the tests failed. You can redeploy tests whenever it will be convenient for you.
2) re-write the tests to generate success if you know that the tests in the live environment can fail because of the live data. But whenever you will click the details, you will know that tests failed.